# How to change icon in Add Object menu?

Tags: scripting, customization, add-on

It has always bugged me that Blender add-ons (in this case the *Sapling* add-on for generating trees) have a wall socket as their icon in the *Add* menu, instead of something more custom. I would like to be able to set this icon for these add-ons and for the scripts that I write.

Is it possible to change this icon, either through a custom build of Blender, or by modifying the Python script in any way?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For existing addons you'll have to find its code and change the code where operators are added to menus.

When you write your own add-on, you can choose a different icon by specifying the icon parameter to the operator function with which you register your operator in a function.

From the [Mesh Add operator template](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/blender/release/scripts/templates_py/operator_mesh_add.py) in the Blender text editor the snippet:

```
def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(AddBox.bl_idname, icon='MESH_CUBE')
```

For a list of icons to choose from see the blender documention. There are many places where you can define an icon, but there is only one list. For instance [for the menu function](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67b_release/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.menu) of a layout. It takes an icon, the list is the same.

Icons outside these are not (yet) supported. You can replace the entire icon set though by specifying an icon file at the bottom of the User Interface section of the theme editing in User Preferences

Comment: is there a reason the icon path dialog is gone in 2.68a? Or has it just moved someplace else?

Comment: That looks like a bug.

Comment: Bug report is filed and closed. The Icon thing isn't working yet so the hiding of the field is intentional.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the things already mentioned by jesterKing:

**Icons already in Blender**
To see all the available icons embedded in Blender (and therefore accessible to any addon) you can use the [Icon Enumerator Addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Development/Display_All_Icons).

Often I turn to this post on BlenderArtists by HansPKG, who assembled an image of [most icons and their reference names](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?201093-Icon-Enumeration-Script-%28Blender-2-5%29&p=1729391&viewfull=1#post1729391)

**Adding your own icons**
The blender wiki page [`Dev:2.5/Doc/How to/Add an icon`](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Doc/How_to/Add_an_icon) has a thorough description of how to add icons of your own, this is currently possible only when you do your own Blender builds.

Comment: Nice add about building Blender. Didn't really think of that (as Q was about addons).

Comment: would be neat to be able to load a small raster image as custom icons, it's one of the few areas in Blender that isn't easily customizable.